# How can I set network priority to give me faster download speed?

Tags: networking, internet, bittorrent, priority

I have been trying for some time to torrent at school. They blocked almost every port apart from the necessary ones, (21 80 443 etc.) I finally figured out how to torrent, but with over 200 people accessing the network at once it is fairly slow around 100-200. The speedtest says it has 40mb/s up and down. I dont have admin privileges. Is there a way I can give my IP or computer that I use network priority to give me atleast 1.5mb/s. also I have tested downloading the same thing from home which reaches 1.5mb/s compared to school which is 100-200kbps. Any suggestions will be helpful because i am out of idea.

Comment: And at the moment I am torrenting off a browser using a DL Manager. If someone could tell me how i could torrent off uTorrent directly that would also be very helpful

Comment: Around 100-200 what? Kbps? KB/s?

Comment: While you are considering how to get more than your fair share of bandwidth, you might also ponder the notion of the [categorical imperative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_imperative) when evaluating your motivations.

Comment: kb/s kilobytes not bits

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your school has you locked down pretty tight. What I would recommend is getting a second computer to download files from home, you could use a Remote Desktop connection to start/check up on downloads or set your torrent software to automatically launch files in a folder and use dropbox (free) to sync it from your laptop to -any other cheap computer-. Or alternatively many NAS devices can download torrent files (such as the Patriot GearBox)

Comment: thanks this is possible, but the reason I am doing it at school is because I do not have much download available (25gb) thats for 5 people in a whole month, difficult to download big stuff like series and things of that nature.

Comment: And yet, in a fair world, this is the most fair answer. +1 for you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered a cooperative arrangement with other downloaders?  If you are all getting the same set of shows, maybe you could share or coordinate times.